# Vaadin deployment on local Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, vaadin24

Do I need a production "license" from Vaadin to deploy my Vaadin -Spring Boot war to local Tomcat?

When I run `mvn -P production` it automatically tries to connect to a Vaadin server.

Some questions
a) Was I wrong in my interpretation of Vaadin being an open source framework
b) If I eventually have to deploy my war on cloud, are there Vaadin costs apart from the cloud provider?

```
  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/vkare]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
            ... 37 more 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine project directory for dev mode. Directory '/Users/srinimurthy/JavaProject/sampleapp/target' does not look like a Maven or Gradle project. Ensure that you have run the prepare-frontend Maven goal, which generates 'flow-build-info.json', prior to deploying your application
            at com.vaadin.flow.server.AbstractConfiguration.getProjectFolder(AbstractConfiguration.java:215)
```